# Angularjs:TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

In a angularjs project, I want get user data that sign in and use this data in html form.

For this, I have a `sessionService.js` that send request to server and get response from it. I have below code in `sessionService.js`:

```
          login: function(email, password) {
               $http.post('/api/sessions', {user: {email: email, password: password} })
                    .then(function(response) {
                        service.currentUser = response.data.user;
                        if (service.isAuthenticated()) {
                            //$location.path(response.data.redirect);
                            $location.path('/record');
                        }
                    });
            },
           requestCurrentUser: function() {
                if (service.isAuthenticated()) {
                    alaki = $q.when(service.currentUser);
                    console.log("1"+JSON.stringify(alaki));
                    return alaki;
                } else {
                    return $http.get('/api/users').then(function(response) {
                        service.currentUser = response.data.user;
                        console.log("2"+JSON.stringify(service.currentUser));
                        return service.currentUser;
                    });
                }
            },

            isAuthenticated: function(){
                return !!service.currentUser;
            }
```

When I call `requestCurrentUser`, for first time, `if (service.isAuthenticated())` is run and I get below error in chrome console:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

and if I refresh page again, for this time `else` statement and above error doesn't happend. I don't have any idea for fix this problem. How can I resolve this error?

Comment: It seems that the error may be coming due to the line
`alaki = $q.when(service.currentUser);` because value passed is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $http promise is being returned, you need to add `return` before `$http.post()`. So, the new code would look like - `return $http.post('/api/sessions'..)`